# formulario css y html

Tags: html, css

espero que anden bien.
Necesito ayuda para ajustar un formulario, probe con width pero no hay caso. ya no se como hacer para acomodarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que el area para escribir sea mas larga hacia los lados.

mi codigo html:

```css
    .form{ 
    background: #24303c;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: "calibri";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

    .form1{
    width: 100%;
    background: #24303c;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border: 1px #1f53c5;
    font-family: "calibri";
    font-size: 18px;

}
```

```html
<form class="form">
        <div class="form1">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="visitor_name" placeholder="NOMBRE" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} required>
        </div>
        <div class="form1">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="CORREO ELECTRONICO" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form1">
            <label for="title"></label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="email_title" required placeholder="MOTIVO" pattern=[A-Za-z0-9\s]{8,60}>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <label for="message"></label>
            <textarea id="message" name="visitor_message" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí." required></textarea>
        </div>
            <button type="submit">Enviar mensaje</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Puedes cambiar el ancho del textarea con la propiedad cols: `<textarea cols="60">`

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos opciones.

1)

```
.form textarea{
   width: 100%;
 }
```

2. Agregarle una clase al textarea

```css
.textareaForm{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
        <div class="form1">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="visitor_name" placeholder="NOMBRE" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} required>
        </div>
        <div class="form1">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="CORREO ELECTRONICO" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form1">
            <label for="title"></label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="email_title" required placeholder="MOTIVO" pattern=[A-Za-z0-9\s]{8,60}>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <label for="message"></label>
            <textarea class="textareaForm" id="message" name="visitor_message" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje aquí." required></textarea>
        </div>
            <button type="submit">Enviar mensaje</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahi me funciono, y con los otros como seria? porque tienen un width del 100%, pero no me ocupa todo el espacio a los lados

Comment: La mas facil para todas es agregar una clase de css, por ejemplo, class="estiloInputs". y en el CSS la coloca .estiloInputs{}, con esto quedan los estilos de los inputs general

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres puedes usar CSS

```
  #message{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px
  }
```

De esta manera acepta el ancho que controlas a nivel pixel y acepta también el centrado para que crezca por ambos lados.
Luego está la opción de agregarla el argumento HTML cols para fijar el ancho en columnas, mientras que el centrado lo controlas con CSS. A tu gusto.